# Elliptic integral equality

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I would like to know how to prove following integral equality :

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-k^2}{(1-k^2\sin^2\theta)^\frac{3}{2}}d\theta = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}d\theta \quad \mathrm{where} \quad k^2<1 $$

I would be glad for any suggestions :)

Comment: Does it even hold?! What happens when $k \longrightarrow 1$, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

One can confirm (say, by hand or by a CAS) that two integrands differ by a total derivative:

$$\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 x}=\frac{1-k^2}{(1-k^2\sin^2x)^{3/2}}+\dfrac{d}{dx}\frac{k^2 \sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 x}}$$

But the function inside the derivative vanishes at the limits of integration, so integrating both sides from $x=0$ to $\pi/2$ obtains the desired equality.

Comment: Full disclosure: 1) I found said total derivative by plugging the difference of the two integrands into Wolfram's old [integral calculator](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp). 2) While the above _verifies_ the equality, I wouldn't say it explains it. It's rather like a proof of $\sum_{k=1}^n k =\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ by induction: the argument is valid but hardly illuminating.